# Prevent `(keyboard-quit)` from closing `*compile*` windows

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, compilation

After a recent update to my Spacemacs install, I noticed that `C-g` i.e. `keyboard-quit` closes `*compilation*` buffers that result from an `M-x recompile`. How can I prevent this behavior? I don't want `C-g` to close `*compilation*` buffers.

Comment: Sounds like a Spacemacs bug, if you see the same thing without your init file (`emacs -Q`). If you think so, consider reporting it to the Spacemacs maintainers.

Comment: @Drew It's in fact a Spacemacs "feature", not a bug. lol. `C-g` would rebind to `pupo/close-window` in spacemacs settings. How to disable this feature/bug still needs some diggings though. [Ref](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/54e3cc572f0cbbeb9f1523a5a10442e1c97d13b3/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-purpose/local/spacemacs-purpose-popwin/spacemacs-purpose-popwin.el#L166-L167)

Comment: @TerryTsao: I see. Maybe that info would help as an answer or part of an answer? (And it still sounds like a bug, in the sense that `C-g` in Emacs is generally about canceling an action, but not quitting a window - sounds unusual, in any case.

Comment: @Drew I'm still quite new to Elisp. After a quick scan, I couldn't figure out how to disable this behavior, since I'm not familiar with the relevant [packages](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/54e3cc572f0cbbeb9f1523a5a10442e1c97d13b3/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-purpose/packages.el#L12-L20) `popwin`, `window-purpose` etc. You are making a valid point: `C-g` shouldn't do anything but quit. However, I myself enjoy this feature/bug quite a lot. (Another reason I'm not familiar with how it works, since for me, it just works). Maybe edit the tags (popwin?) to attract the right person?

Comment: @Drew I might have found out how to disable this. Trying on my setting now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit turned out to be [`popwin`](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/popwin). I fixed it with `M-x customize-group RET popwin RET` and removing `compilation-mode` from the "Popwin Special Display Config" list.

Comment: Much better than my hack. 

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```lisp
(defun revert-spacemacs-C-g-doing (func &rest r)
  "Revert rebind of `keyboard-quit' from calling
`pupo/after-display'"
  (apply func r)
  (global-set-key [remap keyboard-quit] nil))

(advice-add 'pupo/after-display :around 'revert-spacemacs-C-g-doing)
```